# How to make a singleton design testable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, singleton

Suppose I have the following singleton:

```
public class ConfigReader
{
    static readonly ConfigReader instance = new ConfigReader();

    private ConfigReader() { }

    public static ConfigReader Instance { get { return instance; } }

    public int RecordsPerPage
    {
        get 
        { 
            var configPath = DB.Table<ConfigSource>().GetFieldValue("Path").ToString();
            if (configSource == "Database")
                return Convert.ToInt32(DB.Table<Configuration>().GetFieldValue("RecordsPerPage"));
            else
                return Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecordsPerPage"]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write a unit test to mock the DB.Table & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings calls within this singleton so that I can test it with unit tests?

Actually this leads to another question for TDD: Do we really necessary to consider the testability when we design the system? Seems not every design can align with the TDD principles, like DI, etc. Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should we consider the testability when designing system? If you write code which adheres [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles, then your system will be testable. So, simply think about whether you need good object oriented design or not.

**Alternative solution** - if you are using Dependency Injection framework, then you can focus only on single responsibility for this class - reading configuration values. Second responsibility (keeping single instance of class) will go to DI framework, and you will be able to use simple constructor injection here.

**Testing your singleton class** - in order to mock class dependencies, you should depend on abstractions instead of implementations. And you should provide implementations via dependency injection. Here you have several options - you can convert `RecordsPerPage` property to method and use parameter injection:

```
public int RecordsPerPage(IConfigSource source)
{
     var configPath = source.GetFieldValue("Path").ToString();
     if (configPath == "Database")
          return Convert.ToInt32(source.GetFieldValue("RecordsPerPage"));

     return Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecordsPerPage"]);
}
```

Now you will be able to pass mock of `IConfigSource` to your singleton (Moq sample):

```
int expected = random.Next();
Mock<IConfigSource> sourceMock = new Mock<IConfigSource>();
sourceMock.Setup(s => s.GetFieldValue("Path")).Returns("Database");
sourceMock.Setup(s => s.GetFieldValue("RecordsPerPage")).Returns(expected);

var reader = ConfigReader.Instance;
var actual = reader.RecordsPerPage(sourceMock.Object);

Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
sourceMock.VerifyAll();
```

If you want to reuse `IConfigSource` for different calls to singleton, then you can declare property for setting it (property injection):

```
public IConfigSource Source { get; set; }
```

And setup source during tests:

```
var reader = ConfigReader.Instance;
reader.Source = sourceMock.Object;
var actual = reader.RecordsPerPage;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solved my problem, and in other words, if a design is not testable, then it is not a good design, correct?

Comment: @daxnet yes, when we are talking about object-oriented design. Testability is a side effect of flexible and reusable design

Comment: So in my case, instead of using a singleton, we can design to use a regular class, passing in the IConfigSource instance as a dependency on the abstraction, then use the IoC container to make it a singleton, thus it should be a better design and is testable. Please correct me if I understood incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: @daxnet yes, that what I'd use - single responsibility principle :)